# javascript global object instance name

Tags: javascript

I have some 'namespaced' syntax:

```
var APP = {};
```

then I have :

```
APP.one_sub_app = function () {}
etc.
```

I create instances of APP objects and I add them to APP.

```
   APP.my_instance = new APP.one_sub_app();
```

I want to keep all my application inside APP. Ok, my app works fine. Now I apply an uglifier that change APP to Z. I need a way to know that Z is APP because (for example) I need a way to deal with Z ( really APP ). I need a way to check if the parent of any object is APP or other object.

Getting the name using a Z.constructor.name could be the solution but in my case Z (APP) is a unnamed object.

Any way to fix that? I dont want to create a custom property,because other external instances I could be looking can have not my custom property. Any way  create an 'autoinstance' of global object with the same name ?

Comment: All instances of `APP` will become `Z`, so what is the problem? Minification should be transparent to you. Unless your global object is destined for use by other applications? If you want to force a name then I think using the indexer syntax with a string will survive minification: `global['APP'] = {};`

Comment: I love it when people feel the pain of global variables. Maybe that's an indication that globals aren't a good fit for your app.

Comment: @BenAston. The problem is that I need a way that Z or other name is APP. I have internal code that need to know that. I think that the only way it to create a 'name' using object.defineProperty name....

Comment: I don't fully grok how uglifiers work. You may find that changing `var APP = {}` to `window.APP = {}` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent renaming the namespace variable by minifier, make it global, e.g. by declaring it *outside* (before) the immediately-invoked function the namespaced functions are defined in:

```js
var APP = {};

(function() {
    APP.foo = function() {/* ... */};
    APP.bar = function() {/* ... */};
})();
```

or just use `window.APP = {};` instead of `var APP = {};`.